# Calling Custom path binaries using System command

Tags: c, linux, path

In a linux box my rpm's used to install my software binaries to a predefined "/opt//bin" and "/opt//lib" , and from some binaries(c executable) i used to call these binaries located in /opt//bin by harcoding its full path using system call.
for example : system("/opt/<my_loc>/bin/myBin");

Now I would like to install my software to a custom path so what's the best approach to call the binaries from the new custom path ?

Comment: Set `PATH` in your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stop hard-coding the path in each system call.  Or at least use a `#define` so you can update it from your old path to your new path. Then you can generate a suitable config file at build-time via a script.

The better approach is to just configure your PATH environment variable correctly, so you can just tell it what binary you want to run.  I order it like this: ~/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin (if your /bin and /sbin is not merged into /usr you will need to add those too).  `system()` uses `sh` which on my system is `dash` so you would set your PATH in ~/.profile and/or /etc/profile.

I don't like a binary path per package, so I use the program `stow` to merge a bunch of per package directories in /usr/local/stow/$package/bin to /usr/local/bin.

Comment: Thanks. Currently I do have config files also under "/opt/myloc/config/" directory, which is been called from C code with absolute path, ex: /opt/myloc/config/myconf.conf , now how do i address this if we are moving in to a custom path.